# Fixing a class to ensure that it adds objects to its list, only if it implements a certain interface - Java

Tags: java, interface, implementation

I've been given a class - GoodPetStoreClient - that makes use of another class - NoisyPetStore - in order to create a list of objects - Cat, Dog and Cow - which implement an interface - MakesSound - and have been asked to modify NoisyPetStore to ensure that GoodPetStoreClient will compile properly. I've been trying to work out what I'm missing, but without luck so far, and would appreciate some more experienced insight.

Thanks!

Here's the code
     public class GoodPetStoreClient {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NoisyPetStore petStore = new NoisyPetStore();
        petStore.addPet(new Cat());
        petStore.addPet(new Cow());
        System.out.println("I bought an animal, and it goes: " + petStore.buyNewestPet().makeNoise()); //moo...
        System.out.println("The rest of the pet store goes: " + petStore.makeHugeNoise()); //meow
        System.out.println("I bought another animal, and it goes: " + petStore.buyNewestPet().makeNoise()); //meow
        petStore.addPet(new Dog());
        System.out.println("The pet store now goes: " + petStore.buyNewestPet().makeNoise());
    }

    private static class CollisionInSpace {
        // makes no sound at all
    }

}
```

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

```
public class NoisyPetStore 
{

    //Stores pets
    private List list;

    public NoisyPetStore()
    {
        list = new ArrayList();
    }

    /* add a pet to the pet store after checking
    * whether or not the object implements
    * <MakesSound>
    * @param o takes in a object of an unspecified 
    * class
    **/
    public void addPet(Object o )
    {
      //check if the instance implements the MakesSound interface
      if(o instanceof MakesSound)
      {
         list.add(o);
      }
   }

   /* get the last pet from the store by accessing
   * the last item in the list, and hence the one
   * which has been added most recently
   **/
   public Object buyNewestPet()
   {
        Object ans = null;
        if (list.size() > 0)
        {
            ans = list.remove(list.size() - 1);
        }
        return ((MakesSound)ans);
    }

    /* creates a string representation of all of the noises
    * made by pets which have been added to the list using
    * a <StringBuilder>
    * @return returns a String representation of all the noises
    * made by the pets in the list
    **/
    public String makeHugeNoise() {
        StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            ans.append(((MakesSound) list.get(i)).makeNoise());
        }
        return ans.toString();
    }
}

public class Cat implements MakesSound
{
   String sound;

   /* Constructor for Cat object
   * takes in no parameters and instantiates 
   * the instance variable sound
   **/
   public Cat()
   {
      sound = "Meeow";
   }

   /* Overrides the <makeNoise> method defined by the
   * <MakeSounds> interface
   * takes in no parameters and returns the sound made
   * by a cat, represented as a <String> {@link String}
   **/
   @Override
   public String makeNoise()
   {
       String s = sound;
       return s;
   }
}

//dog and cow have identical codes to cat, with the exception that they produce the sounds "Woof!" and "Moo!" respectively.
```

Comment: Please, provide the error message, mentioning if it is a compile time or run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this line:

```
public void addPet(Object o )
```

to this:

```
public void addPet(MakesSound aPet)
```

And this:

```
public Object buyNewestPet()
```

to this:

```
public MakesSound buyNewestPet()
```

This would enforce that you will only be able to pass objects that implement `MakesSound` interface to the `addPet` method. You won't need to use `instanceof` to verify this. Also `buyNewestPet()` will return objects that implement `MakesSound` interface, making the methods defined there available for invoking in `GoodPetstoreClient`.

Comment: GoodPetStoreClient still won't compile using NoisyPetStore, though.

Comment: This error keeps on coming up:System.out.println("I bought an animal, and it goes: " + petStore.buyNewestPet().makeNoise()); //moo...
                                                                                        ^
  symbol:   method makeNoise()
  location: class Object

I can't modify GoodPetStoreClient in any way though, and can't see how to modify NoisyPetStore in order to fix this.

Comment: I've updated my answer to accommodate this. If you see any other related errors, please post them here.

Comment: You are welcome. If you find this answers your question, please mark it as the answer.